# Projects Tracking

Tags: windows, windows-7, project-management

I have Multiple Projects at different locations in my system (not network)

Now I work like this:
One day I decided to work on one project because I got an idea
and second I work on another project.

this way I work as per my interest, but this way I do not get to know when is the last time I worked on a project, So I can develop my interest in a project which I had not touched for so many days.
And another problem is because they are stored in a different location so locating all of them one by one and checking what is the progress is hectic.

Now I am looking for a software where I can tell which folder (project) to track and show me details when is the last time I worked on that project by tracking files modified in a folder(project).

A good interface desktop application for Windows 7

Any recommendations please?

Comment: Welcome aboard. I presume that these are hobby projects? To be honest, that's not the best way to do it, jumping from one to another. You will only confuse yourself. Try to be more disciplined and stick to one project at a time. It is ok to have ideas about a project other than the current one, and make notes, but you really ought to pick one and stick with it, or it is unlikely that any will ever be complete, and certainly not with much quality.

Comment: Are they all the same kind of project? E.g all Microsoft Visual Studio, etc? If so, I can help.

Comment: @Mawg Yes, these are just daily ideas pop-up like projects, but thanks I will keep this in my mind and try to work on one project at a time.
Yes, they all are Microsoft Visual Studio projects, mostly desktop and few are the web-based. Thanks

Comment: Then get a To-Do list manager :-)  I really like [TskCoach](http://www.taskcoach.org/), which I can use on both my Windows PC and my Android 'phone & synch the database with DropBox.

Comment: This title needs a re-write to be much more specific.

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lostalloy.LocalHistory-for-Visual-Studio - This could work if you're willing to add labels.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you really should move all projects to an easy to use location. Ideally, they do not depend on their path anyway.

I use Github Desktop to actively track my projects (which are all using Git). It even comes with a default location to use for all your projects, but of course you can just leave them were they are.

It will probably even allow you to open the project in Visual Studio using a shortcut you can configure in its easy, easy settings.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, I think that this is very much the wrong way to do things, but, if you are determined ...

If all projects are under a common directory, in sub-directories, then you just have to look for the oldest file in any subdirectory. Even better, since you say that they all are Microsoft Visual Studio projects, you just need to search for the solution files  (*.sln)

- Download the excellent, free [Double Commander](https://doublecmd.sourceforge.io/).
- Navigate to the parent directory of all of your project directories.
- Click on "Date" to sort files by date (you can click again to reverse the sort order)
- Now you know which one you played with most recently, longest ago

[image]

- Press Alt+F7 for search, enter *.sln for file name
- the result will be a list of all *.sln files in that directory tree

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: It irks me that this answer is applicable...long live git! :)

Comment: It irks me too, when I see people "developing" software in slapdash, non-methodical, ways.